# How to make something solid that dissolves faster than bar soap in water

Tags: water

What is a soap-like material that holds a solid shape, but dissolves completely in water over 10-15 minutes. Think disappearing Rubber Ducky.

Answer (score 2):

Potassium soap is soft.  Vary the sodium-potassium ratio to get what you want.  Leave some glycerin in.  Make the soap from polyunsaturated fats.